# Using Sys.chmod to toggle world-readability in R

Tags: r, posix, chmod, cran

How can I use the `Sys.chmod` function in R to toggle readability by "other", i.e. the equivalent of:

```
chmod o+r myfile
chmod o-r myfile
```

I specifically want to leave the other parts of the mode alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chmod o+r:

```
mod <- file.info('tmp.txt')$mode
Sys.chmod('tmp.txt', mod|4)
```

chmod o-r:

```
mod <- file.info('tmp.txt')$mode
Sys.chmod('tmp.txt', mod&!as.octmode(4))
```